# How to fill OpenCV image with one solid color?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

How to fill OpenCV image with one solid color?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Using the OpenCV C API with `IplImage* img`:

Use [cvSet()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvset#cvSet): `cvSet(img, CV_RGB(redVal,greenVal,blueVal));`

Using the OpenCV C++ API with `cv::Mat img`, then use either:

[`cv::Mat::operator=(const Scalar& s)`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=setto#mat-operator) as in:

```
img = cv::Scalar(redVal,greenVal,blueVal);
```

or [the more general, mask supporting, `cv::Mat::setTo()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=setto#Mat&%20Mat::setTo%28InputArray%20value,%20InputArray%20mask%29):

```
img.setTo(cv::Scalar(redVal,greenVal,blueVal));
```

Comment: Should it be red, green, blue OR blue, green, red? Isn't it blue, green, red in opencv?

Comment: It's Blue, Green, Red. Confrmed

Comment: Actually, OpenCV is channel-order agnostic. You are correct that the most common channel order (on PCs) is `BGR` though this is not very pertinent to this answer. It is generally the user's responsibility to keep track of channel order.

Comment: @AdiShavit can we remove the set color from the picture?

Comment: @ShwetabhShekhar: That question has so many different meanings and answers that it is way beyond the scope of a comment... Try asking it as a full question and provide more context to what you want to do. But answering simplistically, what do you mean by *"removing"* a triplet of values from an existing C array?

Answer (score 44):

Here's how to do with cv2 in Python:

```
# Create a blank 300x300 black image
image = np.zeros((300, 300, 3), np.uint8)
# Fill image with red color(set each pixel to red)
image[:] = (0, 0, 255)
```

Here's more complete example how to create new blank image filled with a certain RGB color

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def create_blank(width, height, rgb_color=(0, 0, 0)):
    """Create new image(numpy array) filled with certain color in RGB"""
    # Create black blank image
    image = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)

    # Since OpenCV uses BGR, convert the color first
    color = tuple(reversed(rgb_color))
    # Fill image with color
    image[:] = color

    return image

# Create new blank 300x300 red image
width, height = 300, 300

red = (255, 0, 0)
image = create_blank(width, height, rgb_color=red)
cv2.imwrite('red.jpg', image)
```

Answer (score 14):

Create a new 640x480 image and fill it with purple (red+blue):

```
cv::Mat mat(480, 640, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(255,0,255));
```

Note:

- height before width
- type CV_8UC3 means 8-bit unsigned int, 3 channels
- colour format is BGR

Answer (score 11):

The simplest is using the OpenCV Mat class:

```
img=cv::Scalar(blue_value, green_value, red_value);
```

where `img` was defined as a `cv::Mat`.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`numpy.full`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html). Here's a Python that creates a gray, blue, green and red image and shows in a 2x2 grid.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

gray_img = np.full((100, 100, 3), 127, np.uint8)

blue_img = np.full((100, 100, 3), 0, np.uint8)
green_img = np.full((100, 100, 3), 0, np.uint8)
red_img = np.full((100, 100, 3), 0, np.uint8)

full_layer = np.full((100, 100), 255, np.uint8)

# OpenCV goes in blue, green, red order
blue_img[:, :, 0] = full_layer
green_img[:, :, 1] = full_layer
red_img[:, :, 2] = full_layer

cv2.imshow('2x2_grid', np.vstack([
    np.hstack([gray_img, blue_img]), 
    np.hstack([green_img, red_img])
]))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow('2x2_grid')
```

Comment: How would you go about doing this with a non-gray color?

Comment: Updated with non-gray example.

Comment: @orangepips, It's a nice answer. By the way, could you tell me if there is any function or operator in android (opencv) for something like [:,0]=1 in python? It is also used on your python code posted.

Answer (score 8):

```
color=(200, 100, 255) # sample of a color 
img = np.full((100, 100, 3), color, np.uint8)
```

Comment: @Amir Dora disagree completely.  This is the best answer here by far, answers the question in the most clear, concise, and direct manner.

Comment: @AmirDora, I completely disagree as well. The answer is concise and answers the question precisely.

Comment: It's a community guideline, always better to follow. But i have removed my comment.

Answer (score 6):

For an 8-bit (CV_8U) OpenCV image, the syntax is:

```
Mat img(Mat(nHeight, nWidth, CV_8U);
img = cv::Scalar(50);    // or the desired uint8_t value from 0-255
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Java for OpenCV, then you can use the following code.

```
Mat img = src.clone(); //Clone from the original image
img.setTo(new Scalar(255,255,255)); //This sets the whole image to white, it is R,G,B value
```

Answer (score 0):

**I personally made this python code to change the color of a whole image opened or created with openCV . I am sorry if it's not good enough , I am beginner  .**

```
def OpenCvImgColorChanger(img,blue = 0,green = 0,red = 0):
line = 1
ImgColumn = int(img.shape[0])-2
ImgRaw  = int(img.shape[1])-2



for j in range(ImgColumn):

    for i in range(ImgRaw):

        if i == ImgRaw-1:
            line +=1

        img[line][i][2] = int(red)
        img[line][i][1] = int(green)
        img[line][i][0] = int(blue)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you are about to answer an old question (this one is almost 10 years old) that already has an accepted answer (that is the case here) please ask yourself: Do I really have a substantial improvement to offer? If not, please consider refraining from answering.