# cvSet() how to use this function to set color only to a pixel

Tags: c, image, opencv

i have a problem with a C program.
I want to set a color to my image, load with the openCV library. But i founded only this function that set all the image to one solid color. At this page:

[How to fill OpenCV image with one solid color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337902/how-to-fill-opencv-image-with-one-solid-color)

But i want to set only my given (i,j) pixel. How could i do?

Thanks

EDIT:
( i are my rows, j my columns )
And `<Vec3b>` is for what? Because i received this errors:

3Drenderer.c:120:49: error: request for member ‘at’ in something not a structure or union
3Drenderer.c:120:53: error: ‘Vec3b’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3Drenderer.c:120:53: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
3Drenderer.c:120:73: error: ‘B’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3Drenderer.c:121:75: error: request for member ‘at’ in something not a structure or union
3Drenderer.c:121:101: error: ‘G’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3Drenderer.c:122:49: error: request for member ‘at’ in something not a structure or union
3Drenderer.c:122:77: error: ‘R’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Answer (score 0):

If your image is named `I`

```
I.at<Vec3b>(j,i) = Vec3b(B,G,R);
```