# how to fill color into image, by considering small matrix size 3*3 or 6*6? in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, mat

How can i fill color to required image of type Mat,by considering the small matrix of 3*3,i searched the net,but couldn't find correct answer to implement,i hope u guys can help better,thanks in advance ,or else please upload some links if possible.

Comment: rephrase this post to emphasizes on your issue. It is unclear right as it is.

Comment: i'm reading image to Mat variable in my code and want to modify the required small matrix 3*3 or 6*6,which i need to process,[like changing color of required matrix],i'm actually implementing inference   difference in mean method so. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827511/about-different-color-input-on-an-rgb-image, please look in to link.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i fill color to required image of type Mat?

If you want to change the value of a `Mat` image, you can do as follows:

- Grayscale (`8UC1`):

  ```
  uchar intensity = img.at<uchar>(y, x) = value_you_want_to_fill;
  ```
- Color image (`BGR` color ordering, the default format returned by `imread`):

  ```
  img.at<Vec3b>(y, x) = Vec3b(B_value, G_value, R_value);
  ```