# can't change all pixel in image Mat opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I have a gray image and I want to change all pixel value in that image into white colors.

I try these code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
```

`cv::Mat img = cv::imread("C:/mata.jpg");

for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++)
    {
        img.at<uchar>(i, j) = 255;
    }
}
imshow("result", img); }`

size of image: 37 x 29

I've checked the total of pixel in that loop, and the result, I can access all pixel but not all pixel in image changes into white color (just a quarter of image changes into white colors, the others still have the same color as original image).

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Your image is not grayscale. It is being loaded as a 3 channel image. Try this: `cv::Mat img = cv::imread("C:/mata.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your image is grayscale?... or is it a RGB image with all components equal?

Comment: I tried imread("image", CV_BGR2GRAY) but it has the same result. @sgarizvi it works!!! thanks.. :)

Comment: @anne The correct syntax is `imread("image", 0)` The flag you used, is for converting images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image may be a RGB image that is visualized as grayscale.  This means that each channel shares the same values, or the red, green and blue values are all equal.  Try reading the image in as grayscale, or perform a manual conversion from colour to grayscale.

So do this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("C:/mata.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE); // Change here

    for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++)
            img.at<uchar>(i, j) = 255;

    imshow("result", img);
}
```

... or do this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {    
    cv::Mat img_colour = cv::imread("C:/mata.jpg"); // Change here

    cv::Mat img;
    cv::cvtColor(img_colour, img, cv::CV_BGR2GRAY); // Change

    for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++)
            img.at<uchar>(i, j) = 255;

    imshow("result", img); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As suggested in other answers and the comments, you are reading the image as BGR instead of grayscale.
Another approach which will work for both grayscale and color images it to avoid the manual loop altogether and write this instead:

```
img.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(255));
```

or

```
img = cv::Scalar::all(255);
```

See more variations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4339441/135862).